# Conditional formatting on pivot table that will compare one column (column C) with previous column (Column B)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

[image]

Trying to do conditional formatting on pivot table that will compare one column (column C) with previous column (Column B) and if Column C is a percent higher/lower than Column B then the cell should turn Green or Red. Would like this to work across pivot (each column is weeks)."

I have tried using a formula =$C2>=$B2, but this will only work on the 2 columns selected and also only based on the numbers not a percentage

Comment: so what would be the color if it is NOT a percent higher/lower? also are the column number fixed or dynamically change from time to time?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be this:

1. I calculate the difference between the two values.
2. Then I check if that difference is larger than 1%.
3. I make it to a TRUE/FALSE statement as conditional formatting only accept this kind of return value.

So for green values:

```
=IF($C4<>"",OR((($C4/$B4)-1)>=0.01,$C4=$B4),FALSE)
```

To deal with empty values in column B, as 1/0 is not possible.

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK($B4),$C4<>""),OR((($C4/0.01)-1)>=0.01,$C4=$B4),FALSE)
```

And then for the Red Values

```
=AND((($C4/$B4)-1)<0.01,$C4<>"",$B4<>"")
```

See example below:

[image]